# Keep getting something like 2/8HASH(0x73609f8) when I print a hash value

Tags: perl

I have checked that `$clause` is a hash reference and also that it has two keys `children` and `joiner` by iterating `keys %{$clause}`

To see what value `children` key holds, I printed them.

```perl
sub _charts_to_conditions {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $clause = $self->_charts;

    warn(%{$clause}.{'children'}); # print logs in server

    # some other logics
}
```

The printed values were

```perl
2/8HASH(0x73609f8)
```

I wasn't sure what 1/8 would mean, but as it looked like a hash ref, I tried to print it too.

```perl
warn(%{%{$clause}.{'children'}});
```

The result

```
Can't use string ("2/8HASH(0x73609f8)") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at <filename>
```

Now it sounds like `%{$clause}.{'children'}` is a string. But given how useless information `2/8HASH(0x73609f8)` is, I suppose, something was grandly wrong in the first place and I'm only missing it. Can anyone throw light on what would be helpful to try?

Comment: Why not just `$clause->{children}`?

Comment: @tadman That doesn't seem to be allowed with the current configuration. I get "Bareword "children" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at <filename>"

Comment: @PuffedRiceCrackers - Are you sure you're using `->` and not `.`?  `$clause->{children}` shouldn't throw that error.

Comment: Read [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut)

Comment: If you're in fussy mode, `$clause->{'children'}` will do.

Comment: @JimDavis @tadman I did use `.`. `$clause->{children}` just worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `warn(%{$clause}.{'children'});`, the output `2/8HASH(0x73609f8)` is the concatenation (`.`) of two values: `%$clause` in scalar context, which for a non-empty hash in version of perl older than 5.26, returns `number of entries/number of buckets` (Newer versions just return the number of entries in the hash), and the (ill-formed) hash ref `{'children'}`.

You should be using `warn $clause->{'children'};` instead if you want to print the value of that entry.

Comment: That explains my mistake. Thank you!